# What word can I use for "level someone wants to achieve"

Tags: word-choice

If I want to say:

> Level 10 is Larry's _________ (aspired) level?

Does "Aspired" work?

In `Merriam-Webster`, aspired is a verb not an adjective; that's why I was wondering. If not, then what word can I use for "level someone wants to achieve"?

Comment: *Desired* level.

Comment: Using https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aspired+level%2Ctarget+level%2Cdesired+level%2C+ambition+level&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caspired%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctarget%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdesired%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cambition%20level%3B%2Cc0 for the possibilities mentioned so far, shows usage levels as 1. *desired level*, 2. *target level* and very far behind are 3. *ambition level*, 4. *aspired level*

Comment: "Level 10 is the level to which Larry aspires" might be more elegant and idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

"Aspired" seems awkward in this context.  Two clearer alternatives are

> Level 10 is Larry's goal.

and

> Level 10 is Larry's target.